# Statistics Optimal Number of Clusters in massive mixed dataset

Tags: r, clustering, large-data

There are several questions about this problems but they are not as specific as this and none of them have ever been really answered.

Using R, I am working on a `clustering` problem concerning `600,000 observations` and up to `16 variables` both `numerical` and `categorical`.  I decided to go for non-hierarchical algorithm like `k-means`.

I already preprocessed the dataset and it is ready for clustering. However, I need to use a more statistical approach than the `Elbow Method` in order to **suggest** the optimal number of clusters.

For this purpose I have read about `Silhoutte Criterion` and `Gap Statistics`, which are implemented in packages like `NbClust` and `factoExtra`.

At this point appears two related questions:

1. how to compute the Dissimilarity Matrix required as input by Silhoutte Criterion and Gap Statistics on a massive dataset?
2. In the case of mixed variables types, how to overcome the issue of a non-euclidean metric?

Comment: The reason all those duplicates are not answered supposedly is *because* there *is* no answer. All you optimize is some heuristic, that probably is not even very related to your problem. It doesn't really matter much which "optimal" k you chose because of which heuristic. They''ll likely all be bad on such data anyway.

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear. I am asking which Statistical Methods for clustering validation do you suggest to use on a massive dataset composed of numeric and categorical variables. I asked for a statistical """index""" that can be computed on such dataset (no dissimilarity matrix) because in order to give more robustness to the analysis. I am NOT asking what is the **best** number of clusters because I know there is no answer.

Comment: None of the indexes will work reliably. They work on toy problems, but on real data with mixed attributes they are as good as a smart guess. But if the data is large, choose one that can be computed in O(n), obviously.

Comment: I am writing a thesis therefore I want to compare my "smart guess" with the "statistical approach". The objective is to say: even if statistics suggested 3 clusters, I choose 6 clusters because of "domain knowledge".

Comment: Argue *using* the data, not "I didn't like the suggested 3 of an index that may even be incorrectly implemented". Provide a visualization, for example, to prove your point.

Comment: I have the visualization to argue but I do not have what to argue against! I need a robust statistical index that I can compute on massive mixed data set.

Comment: Well, they are all known to be more wrong than right, so why care about arguing against something that one does not expect to work?

Comment: because it is important to motivate my approach. so do you have any idea about the answer?

Comment: If memory is a constraint, you can slice the dissimilarity matrix into different files and load them dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

There exist at least 10 measures for this purpose, and not all are tied to Euclidean distance, nor do all of them require a distance matrix.

While Silhouette is pretty expensive, you can compute it *without* keeping a distance matrix in memory. Because it only needs *linear* access to distances, not random access, and needs every distance just once. If implemented well.

Alternatively, you can also just use a sample. It's unlikely that the result on all points will be very different from the result on just 10% of your data (in evaluation).

But as mentioned before: these measures are known to be just heuristics. The 10 different measures will likely give you at least 5 different values.

Comment: "While Silhouette is pretty expensive, you can compute it without keeping a distance matrix in memory. Because it only needs linear access to distances, not random access, and needs every distance just once. If implemented well." can you elaborate this, please. Do you know whether exists an implementation in R?

Comment: Just look at the definition and implement it without a distance matrix. No, I don't use R much. It's slow except when you write R code. All the fast modules are actually C or Fortran code.

Comment: This was a very interesting insight you gave me. So what language do you use to program?

Comment: 10 years ago I frowned upon Java. By now I see its strengths when it comes to code maintainance and large projects. Yes, you write more lines (or your IDE writes more lines...), but the refactoring functionality is amazing. And as a typed language, you don't get the unexpected errors of scripts if you just make a typo in a function name, for example. Which sucks to do a long computation and then a crash because of a scripting error. Performance is supportingly good. I have seen posts that have generates all kinds of SIMD instructions sometimes. If you want to type less, Kotlin seems to be a ri